# Joining Samba to Active Directory with local user authentication

Tags: active-directory, authentication, samba, user-accounts

I apologise that this is somewhat incoherent, but hopefully someone will be able to make enough sense of this to understand what I'm trying to achieve and provide pointers.

I have a machine with two network interfaces connected to two different networks (one of which it's providing several other services for, such as DNS), running two separate instances of Samba, one bound to each interface. One of the instances is just a workgroup-style setup using share-level authentication, which is all working fine.

The problem is that I'm looking to join the other instance to an MS Active Directory  domain (provided by MS Windows Small Business Server 2003) to enable a subset of the domain users to access the shares from Windows machines on the other network.

The users who need access from the domain environment have accounts (whose names are all-lowercase versions of their domain usernames) on the machine running Samba, but I'm not sure about how to map the UIDs and everything I've read concerns authenticating accounts on that machine against either AD or another LDAP server. To clarify: I only want the credentials for AD users accessing the non-workgroup Samba instance to be authenticated against AD, not the accounts on the machine running Samba.

I hope this is sufficiently clear.

EDIT: In addition to being able to access the Samba shares from AD, I do also need to be able to access a share on the domain from the machine running Samba but would still like everything non-Samba-related to authenticate locally.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this fairly easily. You need to preform all the steps for configuring users to authenticate to linux via AD (KRB config, joining the domain), up to bot NOT including the PAM changes. Then you just set SAMBA to use winbind as the authentication source. Here is an old copy of an smb.conf I've used to achieve this same effect:

```
#======================= Global Settings =====================================

[global]

# Domain Authntication Settings
        workgroup = <my domain>
        server string = <Sever String>
        security = ads
        passdb backend = tdbsam
        realm = <mydomain.com>
        client use spnego = yes
        ldap ssl = no
# logging
        log level = 5
        max log size = 50
        # logs split per machine
        log file = /var/log/samba/%m.log
        # max 50KB per log file, then rotate
;       max log size = 50

# User settings
        username map =  /etc/samba/smbusers
        idmap uid = 10000-20000000
        idmap gid = 10000-20000000
        idmap backend = ad
;       template primary group = <ad group>
        template shell = /sbin/nologin

# Winbind Settings
        winbind separator = +
        winbind enum users = Yes
        winbind enum groups  = Yes
        winbind netsted groups = Yes
        winbind nested groups = Yes
        winbind use default domain = Yes

#Other Globals
        unix charset = LOCALE
        server string = <my server name>
        load printers = no
        printing =  cups
        cups options = raw

;       printcap name = /etc/printcap
        #obtain list of printers automatically on SystemV
;       printcap name = lpstat
;       printing = cups


#============================ Share Definitions ==============================


[share]
comment = <share comment>
path = /srv/smb/share
guest ok = yes
valid users = "DOMAIN+testUser"
read only = yes
```

Also, if you are using Ubuntu there is a bug in the version that was in the 10.04LTS up to a few months ago that just completely broke this setup (nobody can auth) - grab a version from the SAMBA site if this is the case